# jQuery / Regex: How to compare string against several substrings

Tags: jquery, regex, string, substring, substr

I have a special validation need where **I need to check if a string contains ANY out of several substrings** like the following list:

```
12
23
34
45
56
67
78
89
90
01
```

I am new to jQuery and the only thing I could think of here is the following which doesn't look good to me:

```
if(str.indexOf("12") >= 0 || str.indexOf("23") >= 0 || str.indexOf("34") >= 0 || str.indexOf("45") >= 0 || str.indexOf("56") >= 0 || str.indexOf("67") >= 0 || str.indexOf("78") >= 0 || str.indexOf("89") >= 0 || str.indexOf("90") >= 0 || str.indexOf("01") >= 0){
     // do stuff
}
```

**Is there a better way** where I can compare a string against multiple substrings, e.g. using Regex or arrays ?
**In addition, I would also need to count the number of matches for which I didn't find an approach.**

Many thanks in advance for any help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could convert this to a slightly more maintainable format, without getting into regular expressions. This is one way to use an array to accomplish your goal:

```js
var str = '2042038423408';
// Super-quick one-liner (split here for visibility)
var matchCount = $.grep(['12', '23', '34', '45', '56', '67', '78', '89', '90', '01'], function(num, i) {
    return str.indexOf(num) !== -1;
}).length; // should be 2
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or you could create some nice little re-usable functions:

```js
var valuesToCheck = ['12', '23', '34', '45', '56', '67', '78', '89', '90', '01'];

// Pure JavaScript
function howManyMatches(testString) {
  var matches = 0;
  for (var valueIndex = 0; valueIndex < valuesToCheck.length; valueIndex++) {
    if (testString.indexOf(valuesToCheck[valueIndex]) !== -1) {
      matches++;
    }
  }
  return matches;
}

// Here's the jQuery version again
function howManyMatches2(testString) {
  return $.grep(valuesToCheck, function(num, i) {
    return testString.indexOf(num) !== -1;
  }).length;
}


// Usage
var letsTest = howManyMatches('282982902090229892');
var letsTest2 = howManyMatches2('282982902090229892');

console.log('JavaScript: ' + letsTest); // 2
console.log('jQuery: ' + letsTest2); // 2
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this ! I can't run your code snippet here but this looks great ! :) I will accept as soon as I can. Just two final questions: 1) The array input could be anything here correct, also special characters like a question mark ? 2) It looks like this does the opposite of what I need since it returns non-matches - would I just change it to > 0 instead of -1 to get the matches, right ?

Comment: @TaneMahuta: Yes, any string value should be fine. I just edited with a jQuery version.

Comment: Thanks for the update ! I just added something to my comment.

Comment: @TaneMahuta: Sorry, I misread your question. You would want `!== -1`. I updated my code.

Comment: Awesome, no worries - thanks so much and the explanations are really helpful too ! I'll go with the jQuery version. :)

Comment: I am sorry, just checked this but I don't see 8 matches in the example string you provided. I only count 3 matches there: 90, 90 and 89. Am I missing something here ?

Comment: I didn't fix the comments in the code after we changed non-matches to matches. Sorry. I'll update.

Comment: Update: I tried all your versions. The one-liner works great and returns 2 which is correct for the above example (23 and 34) but I can't get the jQuery version to work and I still think the result there should be 3. :) - I might be testing the jQuery the wrong way. How would I alert the result of this ?

Comment: @TaneMahuta: The easiest thing to do when you see `console.log` statements is to open your browser's development tools (usually through pressing F12), switch to the Console tab, run the code, and view the output.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a RegExp. Easy to maintain and pure Javascript (no jQuery):

```
var string = "20420384213408";
var reg = /12|23|34|45|56|67|78|89|90|01/;
if (string.match(reg)) {
    //do stuff
    console.log(string.match(reg).length);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this as well ! Will try this too. How would I count the matches here ?

Comment: `console.log(string.match(reg).length);`